# Grepping EC2 Instance IDs based on Tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, jq, aws-cli

**Requirement**

For EC2 instances, if the Name tag is empty or tag itself not there for particular instances I want to display the instance IDs.

For all EC2 instances, if Schedule tag has the below values only. any value apart from that it should show instance IDs.

Allowed values:

- Yes
- yes
- No
- no

I tried these commands:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids "${line}"| jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[].Key'|grep Schedule` ]] || echo $line >> without_id.txt

aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids "${line}"| jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[].Key'|grep Name` ]] || echo $line
```

Comment: Hi. I've noticed that you have lots of questions with answers, yet not a single answer was ever accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice, but it also reduced duplicates and makes your questions more likely to be answered.

Comment: Also you haven't explained what's wrong with the commands you provider? What do they return, what is expected result, any error messages?

Comment: Hi @Marcin I'm in learning process, still not in a position to answer the quires.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the commands which i mentioned above but it's not fulfilling my requirements that's it.

Comment: I meant that you are not accepting good answer that you got. All your questions appear as unanswered because of that.

Comment: Okay got it @Marcin i apologize for this.

Comment: @G.kalyan - Please follow the [msve] guidelines as much as possible. In particular, an illustrative and informative sample JSON would be helpful, especially if you also include the corresponding expected output.  Please also note that it's not clear what you mean by "if the Name tag is empty" - does that mean the empty string?

Comment: That should have been [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are a bit too hard for a command-line tool.

Instead, I would recommend using a Python script:

```py
import boto3

ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')

# Show Instance ID if there is no Name tag, or the Name tag is empty
for instance in ec2_resource.instances.all():
    name_tags = [tag['Value'] for tag in instance.tags if tag['Key'] == 'Name']
    if len(name_tags) == 0:
        print('No name tag:', instance.id)
    elif name_tags[0] == '':
        print('Empty name tag:', instance.id)

# Show Instance ID if the Schedule tag is not Yes or No
for instance in ec2_resource.instances.all():
    schedule_tags = [tag['Value'] for tag in instance.tags if tag['Key'] == 'Schedule']
    if schedule_tags and schedule_tags[0] not in ['Yes', 'yes', 'No', 'no']:
        print('Bad schedule tag:', instance.id, schedule_tags[0])
```

Comment: Hi @john Thank you very much, it will really help for me.